# FastReport ScriptText does not keep events body when save report

Tags: c#, printing, report, fastreport

in report design i wrote some code in a textbox afterdata event when i want save report xml , in Report.ScriptText Property there is noting in Event Body !!!!
Help Please ,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What version of FR.Net do you use? I guess, that works properly in last version. Try to update it.